# How can I clip both an image and its "tooltip?"

Tags: html, css

Here's the result I'm trying to achieve.
[image: cartoon image of a woman with a speech bubble]

When you hover on the cartoon of the woman, the speech bubble should pop up. When you hover over the word "me" in the speech bubble, the cursor changes to a question mark indicating that it's a link. I have two related problems. Firstly, I want to clip the cartoon image so that the speech bubble appears only when the cursor is on the actual image, and not just when it crosses the threshold of its containing div. However, if I use a polygonal clip path on the cartoon, it also clips off any part of the speech bubble that is outside the border of the cartoon. Secondly, I want the speech bubble to appear only when you hover over the cartoon, not when you hover over the space occupied by the bubble itself. I can achieve this by specifying something like "janes-bubble:hover {visibility: hidden;}". That will prevent the bubble from popping up when hovered over. The problem is that it will also hide when I slide the cursor off of the cartoon meaning I can't get to the "me" link. So, I need it to not pop up unless the cartoon is hovered, but then stay put once the cartoon is hovered, so that the link is available to click on.

Here's my code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #c5f5f0;
}

.janes-face {
  position: relative;
    background: transparent url(https://sodyot.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/portrait-jane.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100%;
    width: 350px;
    height: 335px;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.janes-face:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.janes-line {
    position: absolute;
  /*width; 200px;
  height: 100px;*/
  background: transparent url(https://sodyot.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/speech-bubble-round-r-e1627134718615.png) no-repeat top center;
  font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;
  left: -90%;
    margin-top: -23%;
    padding: 23% 34% 24% 26%;
    color: #0e324c;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: lighter;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    }

.janes-line a {
  color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: help;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #f9745a;
    padding: 0 5px; 
}

.janes-face:hover .janes-line {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kalam:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="content">
  <div class="janes-face">
            <div class="janes-line">"Find out more about <a href="#">  me  </a>."</div><!--end janes-line-->
        </div><!--end janes-face-->
</div>
```

This may not be doable without a script, which is fine, but I've actually got 7 of these all with slightly different positioning. Open to any solution.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding. I see you want the speech bubble to come up when the (cut out) face is hovered. And you don't want the bubble to be clipped along with the face. But, as soon as you move from hovering the face to the orange 'me' you will have stopped hovering on the face if the speech bubble is not a child of the face. Could you describe when you want the speech bubble to disappear? Obviously it can't be allowed to disappear when the face is no longer hovered. Will it disappear on a timer or....

Comment: Thank you for asking. That part of the problem isn't when you hover off the cartoon onto the bubble, It's before you ever get to the cartoon. Right now, if you approach the cartoon from anywhere the bubble (invisibly) sits on the page, it pops up "out of nowhere" which looks silly. If I specify "janes-line:hover {display:none;}" it prevents the random pop-up, but then makes it disappear when you leave the cartoon's space which of course makes it impossible to get to the "me" link. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is finding a way of making the speech bubble appear in its entirety on hover while having hover on the face only, not on its container.

A part way to this, which may be practical as the user probably won't notice the slight difference (being able to continue to hover around the face once hovered on the face) is to have the face defined by a clip path, as mentioned in the question, but remove that clip path on hovering.

This snippet just uses a simple diamond clip path, and the background of the element has been made red just so you can see it. Obviously you'll want to put in your own more detailed clip path around the cartoon.

All that is needed otherwise is to remove the clip path on hover.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #c5f5f0;
}

.janes-face {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);
  position: relative;
    background: url(https://sodyot.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/portrait-jane.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-color: red;
  background-size: 100%;
    width: 350px;
    height: 335px;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.janes-face:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  clip-path: none;
}

.janes-line {
    position: absolute;
  /*width; 200px;
  height: 100px;*/
  background: transparent url(https://sodyot.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/speech-bubble-round-r-e1627134718615.png) no-repeat top center;
  font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;
  left: -90%;
    margin-top: -23%;
    padding: 23% 34% 24% 26%;
    color: #0e324c;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: lighter;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    }

.janes-line a {
  color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: help;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #f9745a;
    padding: 0 5px; 
}

.janes-face:hover .janes-line {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kalam:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="content">
  <div class="janes-face">
            <div class="janes-line">"Find out more about <a href="#">  me  </a>."</div><!--end janes-line-->
        </div><!--end janes-face-->
</div>
```

Comment: That's very clever. It didn't occur to me to nullify a previous declaration with "none." Thank you.